# How to read in SMS in thread view in my custom adaptor in list view on android

Tags: java, android

Am creating an Texting  app in android . Is there any way to read the context of Text in thread view from android  . It should be grouped based on single user(thread -id)

As of now I can retrieve the text in android in my app using list view . But I got separate message for each text by time . I would like to group based on number like default text app in android. Kindly suggest the way to retrieve or comment pls ..,

Comment: Did you try t solve this ? any attempt?

Comment: I tried . Failed . Am using custom adaptor to read the text . Share the code later . Somewhat struck now .